# How to know the created date/ last modified date of Field Security Profiles in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

Currently I am investigating for few issues in my CRM implementation, and I believe some of the changes were not done by me, especially in Field Security Profiles and Teams.

Do we have any provision in CRM which can show who has done what changes and when! this would ideally help me finding out right person to contact as we work in a shared development environment.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both of these entities you have fields like 'createdby', 'modifiedby', 'createdon' and 'modifiedon'. Remember that fileds 'modified...' contains information about last changes made. You can list all these fields in 'advanced search'.

Answer (score 1):

Run this query in FetxhXML Builder

```xml
<fetch count="50" >
  <entity name="fieldsecurityprofile" >
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="modifiedby" />
    <attribute name="createdby" />
    <attribute name="modifiedon" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

After executing the query, choose Friendly Names in the Display Options menu to see the names of the users who last made changes.